# convert struct to array in spark data frame

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, struct

I have a dataframe in spark like below.

```
{"emp_id":1,"emp_name":"John","cust_id":"c1","cust_detail":[{"name":"abc","acc_no":123,"mobile":000},{"name":"abc","acc_no":123,"mobile":111},{"name":"abc","acc_no":123,"mobile":222}]}
```

I am looking for the output like below.

```
{"emp_id":1,"emp_name":"John","cust_id":"c1","cust_detail":[{"name":["abc"],"acc_no":[123],"mobile":[000,123,222]}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want something:
First Explode the column & then aggregate back.

```
  val spark:SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().master("local[1]")
  .appName("learn")
  .getOrCreate()

val inputdf = spark.read.option("multiline","false").json("C:\\Users\\User\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\source_file.txt")

val newdf1 = inputdf.withColumn("cust_detail_exploded",explode(col("cust_detail"))).drop("cust_detail")

val newdf2 = newdf1.select( "cust_id", "emp_name","emp_id","cust_detail_exploded.mobile", "cust_detail_exploded.acc_no","cust_detail_exploded.name")

val newdf3 = newdf2.groupBy("cust_id").agg(array(struct(collect_set(col("mobile")).as("mobile"),collect_set(col("acc_no")).as("acc_no"),collect_set(col("name")).as("name"))).as("cust_detail") )

newdf3.printSchema()

newdf3.write.json("C:\\Users\\User\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\newww.txt")
```

Output:

```
{"cust_id":"c1","cust_detail":[{"mobile":["111","000","222"],"acc_no":["123"],"name":["abc"]}]}
```

[image]

Comment: That helped me to solve the issue. Thank you !!